# Has the 4th edition d&d the same box as the 1st (or did I dream it)?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

Yesterday I saw a pre-packaged full D&D set, and it had the familiar red box of the first edition. I was pleased to see it, but reading on the back it appeared like a 4th edition pack. Was I dreaming (I have a very bad cold, so I may have indeed) or did they indeed recycled the 1st edition design for the box ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They have used the same artwork on the current 4th edition starter set as was used in the "Red Box D&D" basic set in the 80's.  It's not the "original" version of D&D (d&d -original- was actually a set of white books that predated the red set by some time) but no, you're not dreaming ;)

Interestingly enough, I think that red box set and the artwork on it has become somewhat iconic.  Thinkgeek currently has a shirt with the design as well.

A lot of people cut their teeth on the red box and the nostalgia rating is pretty high, which is likely part of the marketing reasoning for reusing the design.

Comment: The nostalgia aspect alone is enough to make me want to buy it even though I own the applicable 4E books!

Comment: I know what you mean, I've got quite a collection of 3.x books and haven't been playing D&D for a while so i've avoided getting any of the 4e books - but it was very very tempting to pick up that box set ;)

Comment: Well, it *is* meant to be a standalone product...